# SELECT INTO not working in stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to store multiple variables at the same time but for some reason, this piece of code in my script doesn't appear to be working. Even if I remove all the variables and only try storing one, it still fails.

Keeps telling me the following:

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT
t1.last4D' at line 3**

```
BEGIN

SELECT
t1.json,
t1.uuid,
t1.type,
t1.status,
t1.holder,
t1.bin,
t1.last4Digits,
t1.expiryMonth,
t1.expiryYear,
t1.amount,
t1.currency,
t1.resultCode,
t1.processingTime,
t1.paymentType,
t1.threeDSecure,
t1.paymentBrand,
t1.recurringType,
t1.clearingInstitute,
t1.merchantTransactionId,
t1.referencedId,
t1.registrationId,
t1.divisionName,
t1.divisionUuid,
t1.merchantName,
t1.merchantUuid,
t1.channelName,
t1.channelUuid,
t1.channelLogin,
t1.channelPwd
INTO
@json,
@uuid,
@type,
@status,
@holder,
@bin,
@last4Digits,
@expiryMonth,
@expiryYear,
@amount,
@currency,
@resultCode,
@processingTime,
@paymentType,
@threeDSecure,
@paymentBrand,
@recurringType,
@clearingInstitute,
@merchantTransactionId,
@referencedId,
@registrationId,
@divisionName,
@divisionUuid,
@merchantName,
@merchantUuid,
@channelName,
@channelUuid,
@channelLogin,
@channelPwd
FROM transactions t1
WHERE t1.uuid = '8ac9a4a76fda645f016fdfcacb4926c8';

END
```

**The full stored procedure**

```
BEGIN

SELECT
t1.json,
t1.uuid,
t1.type,
t1.status,
t1.holder,
t1.bin,
t1.last4Digits,
t1.expiryMonth,
t1.expiryYear,
t1.amount,
t1.currency,
t1.resultCode,
t1.processingTime,
t1.paymentType,
t1.threeDSecure,
t1.paymentBrand,
t1.recurringType,
t1.clearingInstitute,
t1.merchantTransactionId,
t1.referencedId,
t1.registrationId,
t1.divisionName,
t1.divisionUuid,
t1.merchantName,
t1.merchantUuid,
t1.channelName,
t1.channelUuid,
t1.channelLogin,
t1.channelPwd
INTO
@json,
@uuid,
@type,
@status,
@holder,
@bin,
@last4Digits,
@expiryMonth,
@expiryYear,
@amount,
@currency,
@resultCode,
@processingTime,
@paymentType,
@threeDSecure,
@paymentBrand,
@recurringType,
@clearingInstitute,
@merchantTransactionId,
@referencedId,
@registrationId,
@divisionName,
@divisionUuid,
@merchantName,
@merchantUuid,
@channelName,
@channelUuid,
@channelLogin,
@channelPwd
FROM transactions t1
WHERE t1.uuid = uuid;

SET @count = JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(@json, 'one', '$.payload.customParameters.SHOPPER_userId');

IF @count = 1 AND @paymentType = 'DB' THEN

IF(JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(@json, 'one', '$.payload.customParameters.SHOPPER_scheduleId') = 1)
THEN
    SET @scheduleId = JSON_EXTRACT(@json, '$.payload.customParameters.SHOPPER_scheduleId');
ELSE
    SET @scheduleId = NULL;
END IF;

IF(JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(@json, 'one', '$.payload.customParameters.SHOPPER_clientId') = 1)
THEN
    SET @clientId = JSON_EXTRACT(@json, '$.payload.customParameters.SHOPPER_clientId');
ELSE
    SET @clientId = NULL;
END IF;

IF(JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(@json, 'one', '$.payload.customParameters.SHOPPER_source') = 1)
THEN
    SET @source = JSON_EXTRACT(@json, '$.payload.customParameters.SHOPPER_source');
ELSE
    SET @source = 'MOTO';
END IF;

INSERT INTO payments
(`clientId`,
`uuid`,
`type`,
`source`,
`status`,
`holder`,
`bin`,
`last4Digits`,
`expiryMonth`,
`expiryYear`,
`amount`,
`currency`,
`resultCode`,
`resultDescription`,
`processingTime`,
`paymentType`,
`threeDSecure`,
`paymentBrand`,
`recurringType`,
`clearingInstitute`,
`merchantTransactionId`,
`scheduleId`,
`referencedId`,
`registrationId`,
`userId`,
`divisionName`,
`divisionUuid`,
`merchantName`,
`merchantUuid`,
`channelName`,
`channelUuid`,
`channelLogin`,
`channelPwd`)
VALUES
(@clientId,
@uuid,
@type,
@source,
@status,
@holder,
@bin,
@last4Digits,
@expiryMonth,
@expiryYear,
@amount,
@currency,
@resultCode,
JSON_EXTRACT(@json, '$.payload.result.description'),
@processingTime,
@paymentType,
@threeDSecure,
@paymentBrand,
@recurringType,
@clearingInstitute,
@merchantTransactionId,
@scheduleId,
@referencedId,
@registrationId,
JSON_EXTRACT(@json, '$.payload.customParameters.SHOPPER_userId'),
@divisionName,
@divisionUuid,
@merchantName,
@merchantUuid,
@channelName,
@channelUuid,
@channelLogin,
@channelPwd);

END IF;

END
```

Comment: If you remove all variables and just execute the SELECT ... FROM, does it work? Try both inside stored procedure and as a standalone query

Comment: Please provide full stored procedure code

Comment: The error message doesn't match the query. It says `SELECT t1.last4D`, but that the first column after `SELECT` is `t1.json`.

Comment: I suspect your missing a `DELIMITER //` or similar statement before you attempt to define the procedure

Comment: I've included the full stored procedure guys. Strange thing is the SP doesn't throw an error but it also isn't doing the insert either. Breaking the code down I saw the initial SELECT was throwing an error, hence why I think that may be the issue. The SELECT FROM works fine by the way @JoakimDanielson.

Comment: You're right @Barmar which is why I'm further confused.

Comment: I've created the SP using PHPMyAdmin which I think inclused DELIMITER by default @Nick.

Comment: The error can't be coming from this stored procedure.

Comment: There is no `SELECT t1.last4D` in this procedure. Perhaps it's in an `INSERT` trigger?

Comment: json is a reserved keyword in MySql, what happens if you write \`json\` instead in the SELECT list? `SELECT
\`json\`,
t1.uuid,
t1.type,...`

Comment: Are you sure you are running the stored proc from the same server you are editing it? (It would not be the first time someone was writing proc changes to one db and running tests off another one with an older version.)